# The run result of flume and test flume

Tags: flume

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcAoO.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lQ41.jpg)

```js
my flume configuration file is as follows:

a1.sources = r1
a1.sinks = k1
a1.channels = c1
# Describe/configure the source
a1.sources.r1.type = exec
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sources.r1.command = tail -F /home/hadoop/flume-1.5.0-bin/log_exec_tail
# Describe the sink
a1.sinks.k1.type = logger
# Use a channel which buffers events in memory
a1.channels.c1.type = memory
a1.channels.c1.capacity = 1000
a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 100
# Bind the source and sink to the channel
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

And start my flume agent with the following stript:
bin/flume-ng agent -n a1 -c conf -f conf/flume_log.conf -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console

question 1: the run result is as follows, however I don't konw if it run successful or not!

question 2: And there is the sentences as follows and I don't know what the mean is about "the queation of flume test":

NOTE: To test that the Flume agent is running properly, open a new terminal window and change directories to /home/horton/solutions/:
horton@ip:~$ cd /home/horton/solutions/
Run the following script, which writes log entries to nodemanager.log:
$ ./test_flume_log.sh
If successful, you should see new files in the /user/horton/flume_sink directory in HDFS
Stop the logagent Flume agent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your flume configuration, whenever the file `/home/hadoop/flume-1.5.0-bin/log_exec_tail` is changed, it will do a tail operation and append the results in the console.

So to test it working correctly,

```
1. run the command bin/flume-ng agent -n a1 -c conf -f conf/flume_log.conf -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
2. Open a terminal and add few lines in the file /home/hadoop/flume-1.5.0-bin/log_exec_tail
3. Save it
4. Now check the terminal where you triggered flume command
5. You can see newly added lines displayed
```